# framework 2.0 leer appsettings desde web.config

Tags: c#

estoy trabajando en una aplicación que esta compilada con framnework 2.0
por razones de compatibilidad, no se puede pasar la app a otro framework.
necesito leer un valor desde el archivo web.config desde la seccion appsettings.

alguien conoce alguna forma de hacer esto con este framework en particular?

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En tu archivo config declaras lo siguiente dentro del nodo

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MyKey" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

En tu código la obtienes

```
string my_key = System.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"]
```

Es posible que tengas que agregar la referencia System.Configuration a tu proyecto ya que no reconoce a la clase ConfigurationManager por si sola.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias opciones según la "necesidades"

Por supuesto que tienes la forma por código, allí nos ayudamos por la clase  [ConfigurationManager](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=netframework-2.0) dentro del namespaces System.configuration

Ejemplo si tenemos

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ForceSide" value="DarkSide"/>
 </appSettings>
```

Para obtener su valor

```
ForceSide.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ForceSide"];
```

Para el nombre completo con namespaces

```
ForceSide.Text = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ForceSide"];
```

Tambien lo puedes leer directamente en los webcontrols con lo que se llama [Expresiones ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)
Ejemplo en un literal...

```
<asp:Literal ID="ForceSide2" Text="<%$ AppSettings: ForceSide %>" runat="server" />
```

NOTA: Recuerda que comienza con el signo $ (que generalmente colocamos =) ..Text="**<%$ AppSettings:**

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar:

- [ConfigurationManager](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=netframework-2.0)
- [Expresiones ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)